# URLs in external references show up as question marks

Tags: bibtex, urls

So I have several external references like this one

```
@misc{epa_2013,
  author = {EPA},
  title = {National Pollutant Discharge Elimination System},
  url = "{\url{http://cfpub.epa.gov/npdes/}}",
  note = "Accessed: 2/6/2013",
}
```

And when I compile my document, I get question marks instead of a URL:

[image: Rendered Bibtex]

I have the following preamble:

```
\documentclass{tJDE2e}

\title{{\itshape International Journal of Digital Earth} \break Name of Paper}
\author{Our Authors}

\usepackage{graphicx} % support the \includegraphics command and options
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{subfigure} 
\usepackage{placeins}


\usepackage{url}


%needed for correctly facing smart quotes
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\date{} 
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
```

And for the references section, I have this:

```
\bibliographystyle{tJDE}
\bibliography{reference}
```

I've tried removing the `\url`, I've tried changing the `url` package to `hyperref`...no matter what I do, I can't seem to get the URLs to render as actual URLs.

EDIT: here is the tJDE2e template for the Digital Earth journal

http://www.tandf.co.uk/journals/authors/tjdelatex.zip

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: The `tjDE2e` class and the `tJDE` bibliography style aren't available on CTAN, so please provide a link.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added the link to the journal's template/style guide at the end.

Comment: The question marks stem from missing years, and your bibliography style seems to insist on them, even in `misc` entries.

Comment: Hmm. So I tried adding years. That gets rid of one set of question marks (and the ones in the citations in the paper as well), but the URL still doesn't display in the bibliography. I still get ??? at the end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bibliography style you use, `tJDE`, does not recognize `url` fields in bibliography entries. Use the `note` field for that. The question marks stem from missing `year` fields that the style enforces even for `misc` entries (violating the standard). The question marks at the end stem from missing `accessed` fields that are required for `misc` entries (violating the standard). Since you have that information, move it there:

```
@misc{epa_2013,
  author = {EPA},
  title = {National Pollutant Discharge Elimination System},
  year = 2013,
  note = "\url{http://cfpub.epa.gov/npdes/}",
  accessed = "accessed 2/6/2013",
}
```

should work.

Comment: This won't work with the new sigplan/sigconf acmart.cls style.

Comment: @mafp If year is not available in citation, then it returns ????. Is there any way possible to get rid of question marks for non-available fields.

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi did you figure out how to work in case of citations without year?